# Reexpressing the higher inductive-inductive surreals with only two mutual subdefinitions

Tags: number-theory, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In $\S 11.6$ of [the HoTT book](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/), the authors describe Conway's surreal numbers in terms of a higher inductive-inductive definition with three mutual subdefinitions.  However, it seems to me that only two will do just as well, by collapsing the very similar definitions of $\lt_\rm{No}$ and $\le_\rm{No}$ into one inductive family indexed over a boolean, so that we end up with the following definition (assuming a typically ambiguous universe designator $\cal{U}$):

$$
\rm{No} : \cal{U}\\
\rm{Rel}_\rm{No} : \rm{No} \to \rm{No} \to \bf{2} \to \cal{U}\\
\rm{cuts}_\rm{No} : \Pi_{\cal{L}, \cal{R} : \cal{U}} \Pi_{\rm{cut}_\cal{L} : \cal{L} \to \rm{No}} \Pi_{\rm{cut}_\cal{R} : \cal{R} \to \rm{No}} (\Pi_{L : \cal{L}} \Pi_{R : \cal{R}} \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(\rm{cut}_\cal{L}(L), \rm{cut}_\cal{R}(R), \rm{0}_\bf{2})) \to \rm{No}\\
\rm{eq}_\rm{No} : \Pi_{x, y : \rm{No}} \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(x, y, \rm{1}_\bf{2}) \to \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(y, x, \rm{1}_\bf{2}) \to x =_\rm{No} y\\
\rm{joint}_{\rm{Rel}_\rm{No}} : \Pi_{\cal{L}^\rm{L}, \cal{R}^\rm{L}, \cal{L}^\rm{L}, \cal{R}^\rm{L} : \cal{U}} \Pi_{\rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{L} : \cal{L}^\rm{L} \to \rm{No}} \Pi_{\rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{L} : \cal{R}^\rm{L} \to \rm{No}} \Pi_{\rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{R} : \cal{L}^\rm{R} \to \rm{No}} \Pi_{\rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{R} : \cal{R}^\rm{R} \to \rm{No}} \Pi_{\xi^\rm{L} : \Pi_{L : \cal{L}^\rm{L}} \Pi_{R : \cal{R}^\rm{L}} \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(\rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{L}(L), \rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{L}(R), \rm{0}_\bf{2})} \Pi_{\xi^\rm{R} : \Pi_{L : \cal{L}^\rm{R}} \Pi_{R : \cal{R}^\rm{R}} \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(\rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{R}(L), \rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{R}(R), \rm{0}_\bf{2})} \to (\Pi_{L : \cal{L}^\rm{L}} \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(cut_\cal{L}^\rm{L}(L), \rm{cuts}_\rm{No}(\cal{L}^\rm{R}, \cal{R}^\rm{R}, \rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{R}, \rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{R}, \xi^\rm{R}), \rm{0}_\bf{2})) \to (\Pi_{R : \cal{R}^\rm{R}} \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(\rm{cuts}_\rm{No}(\cal{L}^\rm{L}, \cal{R}^\rm{L}, \rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{L}, \rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{L}, \xi^\rm{L}), cut_\cal{R}^\rm{R}(R), \rm{0}_\bf{2})) \to \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(\rm{cuts}_\rm{No}(\cal{L}^\rm{L}, \cal{R}^\rm{L}, \rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{L}, \rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{L}, \xi^\rm{L}), \rm{cuts}_\rm{No}(\cal{L}^\rm{R}, \cal{R}^\rm{R}, \rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{R}, \rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{R}, \xi^\rm{R}), \rm{1}_\bf{2})\\
\rm{lift}_{\rm{Rel}_\rm{No}}^\rm{L} : \Pi_{x : \rm{No}} \Pi_{\cal{L}, \cal{R} : \cal{U}} \Pi_{\rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{L} : \cal{L} \to \rm{No}} \Pi_{\rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{L} : \cal{R} \to \rm{No}} \Pi_{\xi : \Pi_{L : \cal{R}} \Pi_{R : \cal{R}} \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(\rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{L}(L), \rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{L}(R), \rm{0}_\bf{2})} \Pi_{L : \cal{L}} (\Sigma_{R : \cal{R}} \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(x, \rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{L}(R), \rm{1}_\bf{2})) \to \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(x, \rm{cuts}_\rm{No}(\cal{L}, \cal{R}, \rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{L}, \rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{L}, \xi), \rm{0}_\bf{2})\\
\rm{lift}_{\rm{Rel}_\rm{No}}^\rm{R} : \Pi_{\cal{L}, \cal{R} : \cal{U}} \Pi_{\rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{R} : \cal{L} \to \rm{No}} \Pi_{\rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{R} : \cal{R} \to \rm{No}} \Pi_{\xi : \Pi_{L : \cal{L}} \Pi_{R : \cal{R}} \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(\rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{R}(L), \rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{R}(R), \rm{0}_\bf{2})} \Pi_{y : \rm{No}} \Pi_{L : \cal{L}} (\Sigma_{R : \cal{R}} \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(\rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{R}(R), y, \rm{1}_\bf{2})) \to \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(\rm{cuts}_\rm{No}(\cal{L}, \cal{R}, \rm{cut}_\cal{L}^\rm{R}, \rm{cut}_\cal{R}^\rm{R}, \xi), y, \rm{0}_\bf{2})\\
\rm{eq}_{\rm{Rel}_\rm{No}} : \Pi_{x, y : \rm{No}} \Pi_{\kappa : \bf{2}} \Pi_{p, q : \rm{Rel}_\rm{No}(x, y, \kappa)} p =_{\rm{Rel}_\rm{No}} q
$$

Is there anything wrong with this reformulation?  If so, what?  If not, am I missing something as to why the book's authors might have chose to use the version that they did, rather than using something like this, or something else entirely (or was it just an aesthetic choice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't read your formula, but I don't immediately see any reason why you couldn't collapse the two order relations as you describe (although I haven't checked the details).  But I don't see any advantage in doing so.  The first thing one would want to do after making such a definition would be to extract the "pieces" $<$ and $\le$, since they are what one wants to work with in practice; so why make things more complicated?

Comment: Thanks, Mike!  I had given up hope of this question being answered.

Comment: Sorry, I just recently realized that people were asking questions about HoTT on MSE; I'd only been looking for them on MO.  (-: